# How to compute module of Kahler differentials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Definition of modulo of Kahler differentials $\Omega_{S/R}$ when a ring homomorphism $\phi:R\rightarrow S$ exists is the $S$-free module generated by elements of $R$ modulo the relations $D(s-s')-Ds-Ds',D(rs)-rDs,D(ss')-sDs'-s'Ds$. But how can you compute a modulo of Kahler differentials sxplicitly. Say one picks up the identity homomorphism $R\rightarrow R$, then what will happen?

Comment: For $R\to R$ identity, clearly, you have $\Omega^1_{R/R}=0$, by the description given in the answer by Bernard.

Answer (score 3):

If $S$ is a finitely presented $R$-algebra:
$\;S\simeq R[X_1,\dots,X_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_r)$, then
$$\Omega_{S/R}\simeq \frac{S\, \mathrm dX_1\oplus\dots\oplus S\, \mathrm dX_n}{S\,\mathrm df_1+\dots+S\,\mathrm df_r}.$$

Comment: How do we get this result? Can you introduce a very elementary reference? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's *very* elementary, but you have a nice chapter in Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, ch. 9: Derivations (Cambridge University Press).